# Can print variable but when assigning it to another returns nil (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, variable-assignment

I have written an app in swift and in the part with the problem it has two views with their corresponding view controllers. What the aim of this part is for the user to click a certain cell on controller 1 which opens a modal view with a table view with table view cells to select from. when the user taps one it should return to the controller 1 and update the details text on original cell.
The problem is the label will not update. here is the code:

this code is from the modal views controller. this is the code which gets the selected cell and updates a variable.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    var find = totalProducts[productSectionTitles[indexPath.section]]!
    selectedCell = find[indexPath.row]
    let rootController = TableViewController()
    println("\(selectedCell) from productController from selectedCell variable")
    rootController.updateText(selectedCell)
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.Checkmark
}
```

this code is from controller 1 where the modal view is launched from. this is called from the modal view controller to update the text.

```
func updateText(transferVar: String) {
    println("\(transferVar) from rootController from transfer parameter")
    detailsLabel?.text = transferVar
    println(detailsLabel?.text)

}
```

So the parameter transfers the data perfectly between the modal view controller to rootController and it definitely holds a value because it prints out the correct one. But as soon as I try to assign it returns nil, i discovered this by println() the detailText after it should have assigned. This is what the console prints when you click a cell.

```
Wood4 from productController from selectedCell variable
Wood4 from rootController from transfer parameter
nil
```

I don't know how to get the label to print out the transferVar. I should add that the labels are connected to the views. How do i fix this?

Thanks in advance.
hopefully you understand. :]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Has detailsLabel been loaded yet? If it's an implicitly unwrapped outlet, it likely hasn't been loaded yet and is still nil. Try accessing it without the `?`. Right now it is failing silently, without the `?` it should crash.

In order to make sure that detailsLabel is loaded before assigning to its labels, you can assign in `viewDidLoad()`. A simple way to do this would be to assign an instance variable in `text()` then set the label to that variable in `viewDidLoad()`.

```
var labelText: String!
func text(transferVar: String) {
    println("\(transferVar) from rootController from transfer parameter")
    labelText = transferVar
}
public override func viewDidLoad(){
    detailsLabel.text = labelText
}
```

Comment: I'm still getting the same error? Thanks for the quick answer though @connor

Comment: Its still not working :/ I have copied you new code but it still returns nil?

Comment: is detailsLabel nil in viewDidLoad?

Comment: the nil occurs as soon as the values are assigned to the detailsLabel.text

Comment: check if detailsLabel itself is nil `if detailsLabel == nil { println("nil") }` in viewDidLoad

Comment: for some reason is gives nil when assigning the values in the text() function but when it is loaded in the viewDidLoad it has a value from the storyboard. so basically is starts with a value but as soon as it is assigned it becomes nil. i really don't know why its doing this, it hasn't done anything like this before in other apps

Comment: hey, i only just realised that i haven't explained my self properly. what I have a right detail cell and I want to update the right detail label. is there a special way to do that?